# Is it possible to develop apps with Kendo UI to submit to iOS App Store?

Tags: android, ios, html5

The number of platforms I have to develops apps for is increasing and It brings me lots of stress to learn new technologies for each target platform. I found out that Telerik's Kendo UI is very good to build websites that look and feel native on mobile platforms (e.g. iOS and Android). My question is, is it possible to build HTML5 apps to deploy them on iTunes App Store and Google Play? Please note that I am eager to know the possibility of creating apps (complete apps bundled in standard format of Apple and Google for distribution in their respective mobile app markets) but not websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best advice I can give you is to ask the folks who make Kendo UI.

In general, though, unless the framework targets the web browser specifically, then it's likely their tools compile whatever front-end HTML-like code you've written to native code for the target devices. So unless the native code violoates some other rule pertaining to the "app store" in question, then there shouldn't be an issue. The only other option is to bundle some sort of browser-like thing that acts like a VM for the target device.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can build applications with [Kendo UI Mobile](http://www.kendoui.com/mobile.aspx) and [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) and publish them to an app store (i.e. Apple App Store).